# looping function, animate dont stay the time necessary

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, jquery-animate

and when come the 5 lines, dont respect the time and the line 6 begins  before , I need to make a loop. How can I do for  the line 5 stay all the time I want?

```
function b(){
    $("#imgScale").animate({opacity:"1"}, 1000);
    $("#imgScale").animate({width:"115%",opacity:"1"}, 4000);
    $("#imgScale").animate({opacity:"0"}, 2000);
    $("#imgScale").animate({width:"100%"}, 10);
    setTimeout(function(){$("#imgScale2").animate({width:"125%"}, 4000)},5100);
    setTimeout(function(){$("#imgScale").animate({opacity:"1"}, 2000)},10100);
    setTimeout(function(){$("#imgScale2").animate({width:"100%"}, 10)},12100)
    setTimeout( b(),20000 );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code does not wait for previous animations to be completed. If you want to execute a piece of code after an animation is completed, you can do so as following:

```
$("#imgScale").animate({
   opacity:"1"
}, 1000, function(){
   // This code will happen after the animation has been completed.
});
```